# ViM Syntax File Syn Match using Perl RegEx

Tags: regular-expression, vim, perl

I was wondering if it's possible to use a Perl RegEx in a .vim syntax file instead of Vim Speak.

If I have a syntax file such as

```
/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/none.vim

" Vim syntax file
" Language:     Custom None
" Maintainer:   Nobody

if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

syn match noneIndentError "*Some Vim Speak RegEx*"

hi def link noneIndentError Error

let b:current_syntax = "none"
```

Is it possible to use a Perl RegEx inside of the syn match instead of a Vim Speak one? My RegEx is written for Perl and I can't seem to get it to work in Vim Speak

```
(?:^)(?: {4})*+( {1,})
```

The RegEx just tests for spaces that aren't included in the indented 4 spaces, you can see it here if you'd like

https://regex101.com/r/oBCjY4/1

Comment: What is "Vim Speak"?

Comment: I don't see anything in there that can't be matched in Vim. Are you having trouble with [zero-width matches](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#/zero-width)?

Comment: If this can be matched in Vim that would be amazing but I cannot for the life of me figure it out, it isn't happy with the `*+`

Comment: You don't need the `*+`. It's just an optimization for Perl. A plain old `*` would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following match should do what you want:

```
syn match noneIndentError /^\( \{4\}\)*\zs \{,3\}/
```

Using [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#/%5Czs), you can exclude the pattern before it from the match, so it's a simpler way to write zero-width look-arounds (it's similar to [`\K` in Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK)). Then it matches up to 3 spaces.

Here's how it matches various lines:

[image]

```
      foo #
   bar
     
    
        baz
```

1. 6 spaces followed by text
2. 3 spaces followed by text
3. 5 spaces
4. 4 spaces
5. 8 spaces followed by text

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do, I am unfamiliar with `\zs` but it looks like that was just what it needed

Comment: Just doing a bit of digging and I'm finding some strange functionality with `\zs`. It looks like it breaks some other match expressions, for example if you have `syn match checkNumber "\<[0-9]\+\>"` and then the `\zs` expression following after

Comment: @TheLovelySausage can't reproduce in 8.2-2815: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2PK.png (I did `:syn match checkNumber "\<[0-9]\+\>"`, `:hi link checkNumber Keyword`, `:syn match noneIndentError /^\( \{4\}\)*\zs \{,3\}/`, `:hi link noneIndentError Error`)

Comment: @TheLovelySausage Sometimes using `\zs` and `ze` in `syn match` expressions might pose a problem if you expect the part that's not part of the match to actually match some other `syn match` rule... In those cases, you'll need to do an actual zero-width look-behind or look-ahead. But it's hard to tell you what's wrong with your setup without more details, so perhaps ask a separate question for that if you like. BTW, you might like the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim (oh, I guess already told you about it in another question...)

Comment: Hello again @filbranden !, yes it's me again and it looks like you're right, the first instance of `\zs` is not finding a match so the expression doesn't have a `\ze`. I onlt really know Perl RegEx so this has me baffled. I def want to try the Vim exchange